# When we use sevenzip.dll in my code using c#, geting error The runtime has encountered a fatal error

Tags: c#

when we use sevenzip.dll in my code using C#, geting error

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0xdf7535b8, on thread 0x1a70. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

My code is

```
 SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"D:\\Projects\\XML2U\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\SevenZipSharp.dll");
 SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
 compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
 compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
 compressor.TempFolderPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
 compressor.VolumeSize = 10000000;
 compressor.CompressDirectory(backupFolder, destination);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the path to 7zip.dll in `SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath` call. See this previous question [How would i use Sevenzipsharp with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108205/how-would-i-use-sevenzipsharp-with-this-code)

Comment: Best not to hard-code that path, either. You don't even need to call the method at all, once you've added a reference to `SevenZipSharp, assuming the two DLLs are in the same directory (and they should be).